# How to fix 'subscript out of range' while using a find function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find multiple cells value which is found in a different worksheet, using a for loop.

I have to find a value then use that cells reference to find another cells value. The first find function works fine, but when I try to run the the second find, a 'subscript out of range' run time error occurs.

```
For i = 1 To 6

If Not Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -i).Value = "" Then
Set foundSA = Worksheets("SUBASSEMBLY").Range("B:B").Find(Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, -i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

For j = 2 To 6
    If Not Worksheets("SUB-ASSEMBLY").Range(foundSA.Address).Offset(0, j).Value = "" Then
        Set foundInv = Worksheets("INVENTORY").Range("D:D").Find(Worksheets("SUB-ASSEMBLY").Range(foundSA.Address).Offset(0, j).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        project = InputBox("What project is the assembly assigned to?")
        deploymentLocation = InputBox("What is the location of the project?")
    End If
Next j
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Why do you have one instance of `Worksheets("SUBASSEMBLY")` and a separate instance of `Worksheets("SUB-ASSEMBLY")`? Do you have two sheets, one with the hyphen and one without? Just checking.

Comment: FYI `Worksheets("SUB-ASSEMBLY").Range(foundSA.Address).Offset(0, j).Value` is the long way round of saying `foundSA.Offset(0, j).Value` (assuming that is a typo in subassembly/sub-assembly)